# For each table in array, get min max values for all columns using SQL

Tags: sql, for-loop, teradata, profiler

For a project I need to create a simple data profiler in a Teradata SQL database.

I have a list of tables. For each table in the list, I want to obtain the minimum and maximum values for all its columns. Then I wish to union the results.

The outcome should look something like this:

| table | row | min | max |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| table_1 | row_1 | 0 | 100 |
| table_1 | row_2 | 0 | 99 |
| table_2 | row_1 | 1 | 67 |
| table_2 | row_2 | 16 | 100 |

I'm having difficulties translating my understanding of for loops in Python (the language I'm most familiar with) to SQL.

There surely should be an easy way to approach this in SQL. Hopefully someone can help me out here.

Comment: What's your Teradata version?

Comment: @dnoeth the version we're using is 17.10

Comment: Do you use *teradataml* in Python? There's already a lot of data exploration/cleaning functions in 17.10, e.g. *UniVariateStatistics*, but this one doesn't support non-numeric columns. Besides that a Stored Procedure would be the best way, but you might not have the neccessary access rights.